# human vs machine tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, minimax

in these days i have been struggling with minimax algorithm and i can say i finally understood it ( thank to another post in stackoverflow). Therefore i opened my editor and i tried to implement it into a EXTREMELY simple ( do not blame me for code please :P) tic tac toe, just to give a try out. everything is working, but the computer move function always retrieve me -1. i'm not asking you to give me code, just the "why" it does that. i have searched throught the code many times, but found nothing . The code is probably really similar to another one i found on the web. here's my code :

```
# COMPUTER AI

def computer_move():
    best_move = minimax_recurse(game_board,active_player, 0)
    print "The best move is ", best_move
    make_move(game_board,best_move, active_player)


    print "COMPUTER MOVE DONE"


def minimax_recurse(game_board,player,depth):

    winner = is_winner(game_board)
    if winner == active_player  :
        return 1
    elif winner is not active_player :
        return -1
    elif len(get_move_list(game_board)) == 0 :
        return 0

    if player == player1 :
        other_player = player2
    other_player = player1

    if player == active_player :
        alpha = -1
    alpha = 1

    movelist = get_move_list(game_board)

    for move in movelist :
        board2 = game_board

        make_move(board2,move,player)

        subalpha = minimax_recurse(board2, other_player, depth + 1)

        if player == active_player :
            if depth == 0 and alpha <= subalpha:
                best_move = move

            alpha = max(alpha,subalpha)
            return alpha

        else :
            alpha = min(alpha,subalpha)
            return alpha



# BOARD FUNCTIONS
game_board = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
def print_board(board) :

    for row in board :
        print row

def make_move(game_board,player_move,active_player):

    x = 0
    y = 0
    player_move = int(player_move)
    if player_move == 1 :
        x = 0
        y = 0
    elif player_move == 2 :
        x = 0
        y = 1
    elif player_move == 3 :
        x = 0
        y = 2
    elif player_move == 4 :
        x = 1
        y = 0
    elif player_move == 5 :
        x = 1
        y = 1
    elif player_move == 6 :
        x = 1
        y = 2
    elif player_move == 7 :
        x = 2
        y = 0
    elif player_move == 8 :
        x = 2
        y = 1
    elif player_move == 9 :
        x = 2
        y = 2
    elif player_move >= 10 :
        print "value is too high"
        skip = False
        return board

    if game_board[x][y] == "O" or game_board[x][y] == "X" :
        print "move not avaiable"
        return game_board

    game_board[x][y] = active_player
    return game_board

def is_winner(board):
    for i in range (0,3) :
        if board[i][0] == player1 and board[i][1] == player1 and board[i][2] == player1 :
            return player1

        if board[i][0] == player2 and board[i][1] == player2 and board[i][2] == player2 :
            return player2

    # checking for obliqual, that's quite bad and slow check but it works
    if board[0][0] == player1 and board[1][1] == player1 and board[2][2] == player1 :
        return player1
    if board[0][0] == player2 and board[1][1] == player2 and board[2][2] == player2 :
        return player2

    if board[2][0] == player1 and board[1][1] == player1 and board[0][2] == player1 :
        return player1
    if board[2][0] == player2 and board[1][1] == player2 and board[0][2] == player2 :
        return player2

    return None


def get_move_list (game_board) :

    move = [0]

    for row in game_board :
        for i in row :
            if isinstance(i,int) == True :
                move.append(i)
    move.remove(0)
    return move



# Main Loop
player1 = "X"
player2 = "O"
print_board(game_board)
while True :
    active_player = player1
    # this is for player move
    print get_move_list(game_board)
    player_move = int(raw_input("Please insert your move >>> "))
    make_move(game_board,player_move,active_player)
    print_board(game_board)

    if is_winner(game_board) == player1 :
        print "Player1 is the winner"
        break
    if is_winner(game_board) == player2 :
        print "Player2 is the winner"
        break
    print get_move_list(game_board)
    # computer time
    active_player = player2
    computer_move()
    print_board(game_board)

    if is_winner(game_board) == player1 :
        print "Player1 is the winner"
        break
    if is_winner(game_board) == player2 :
        print "Player2 is the winner"
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Without debugging all your code, one thing that seems wrong is your use of "best_move" variable (global uninitialized) as both a holder for a move as well as holder for -1/0/+1 result of minimax_recurse.  So it's being overwritten by your minmax algorithm.  You need more variables, clearer initialization of them, and consistent usage.

Comment: that's true, but the algorithm is still returning -1 as result, and i still don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the -1 always returning is that `winner is not active_player` returns `True` when `winner` is `None`. You could use a variable to keep track of the other (inactive) player, or you could use the ternary operator: `elif winner is (player1 if player2 == active_player else player2)`

Though that's not the only issue:

```
if player == active_player :      
    alpha = -1    
alpha = 1
```

That will always set alpha to 1. The lines directly above that have the same problem. The variable naming issue pointed out in the other answer is also true.

Comment: oh yeah.. i completely forgot the two checks... i used the ternary operator, but it's giving me a really strange output, did you try it on your machine? and everyway, i was thinking about the algorithm and it's always outputting 1 or 0 or -1 , it will never output the best_move, any ideas?

Comment: You're always overwriting the board when you set `board2 = game_board` and then modify board2. That's causing a lot of problems. If the ternary operator isn't working (maybe you're using an old version of Python?), you could try fixing up the `other_player` definition, and putting that above the win check. Then you can use `elif winner == other_player:`